# PHP String Function, How can I isolate what is in the last set of parens?

Tags: php, string, function

I have to write a string function that takes whatever is in the last parens and put into a new variable, without the parens. In this case, UPS Next Day Air.

```
$oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day Air)';
$newVar = 'UPS Next Day Air';
```

thanks!,

Comment: So you want us to do it for you ? Have you attempted the challenge? Is this homework or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sets `$newVar` to the correct string if there are matching parens in `$oldVar` and to `false` otherwise.

```
$oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day Air)';
$posLastOpeningParenthesis = strrpos($oldVar, '(');
if ($posLastOpeningParenthesis === false) {
    $newVar = false;
}
else {
    $posLastOpeningParenthesis++; // move the position to behind the opening parenthesis
    $posLastClosingParenthesis = strpos($oldVar, ')', $posLastOpeningParenthesis);
    if ($posLastClosingParenthesis === false) {
        $newVar = false;
    }
    else {
        $newVar = substr($oldVar, $posLastOpeningParenthesis, $posLastClosingParenthesis - $posLastOpeningParenthesis);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: is it better to avoid using RegEx if possible and use string functions instead?

Comment: @TomCarden: 'better' is in this case definitely a matter of personal taste. What can be said is that in PHP RegExes are faster for all but the most simple string operations while string functions are almost always easier to read and determine what is happening (which is an advantage when someone (possibly yourself after years) has to change the code slightly later).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day Air)';
$newVar = '';
if (preg_match('/.*\((.+)\)/s', $oldVar, $matches))
{
    $newVar = $matches[1];
} else {
    // the input $oldVar did not contain a matching string
}

var_dump($newVar);
```

Comment: He doesn't want the first one -- he wants the last one!

Comment: I'm lost. Why would that regexp match the first one? It will only match the first one if it's the only one. Please correct me if i'm wrong. I havent tested the code but ... the principle is right I think.

Comment: No you're right. Without close examination, I assumed that the regex found all parentheticals. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day Air)';
$newVar = preg_replace('/.+\((.+?)\)[^\)]*$/', '$1', $oldVar);    
?>
```

Comment: This solution works almost perfectly, but it fails when the input is:
    $oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day) Air)';

It does not correctly detect the matching closing parenthesis to the last opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i answered myself. Hardly elegant, but it works. Could be re-written ...

```
$oldVar = 'United Parcel Service (1 pkg x 4.00 lbs total) (UPS Next Day Air)';
//$newVar = 'UPS Next Day Air';

$pos1 = strrpos($oldVar, '(') +1;
$pos2 = strrpos($oldVar, ')');
$strlen = $pos2 - $pos1;


$newVar = substr($oldVar, $pos1, $strlen);
```

strrpos finds the last occurrence of a character